# Finding semi duplicates

Tags: duplicate-management

I have been given a list of 2000 accounts my sales rep got from some marketing company.  Is there a better way than:

```
SELECT AccountId, Name FROM Account WHERE Name LIKE '%Some row[1] substring%'
SELECT AccountId, Name FROM Account WHERE Name LIKE '%Some row[2] substring%'
SELECT AccountId, Name FROM Account WHERE Name LIKE '%Some row[3] substring%'
```

to find accounts that may match entries on the list?

my thought was to grab a few substrings of the account name and use the Like operator to find accounts that may match.

Comment: Why don't you use [Duplicate Rules](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=managing_duplicates_overview.htm&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=5)?

Comment: The list I am using to compare against are not accounts in salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

You can set WHERE clause with OR (to avoid querying several times):

```
String query = 'SELECT AccountId, Name FROM Account WHERE Name LIKE \'%' + String.join(rows, '\' OR Name LIKE \'%') + '%\'';

Database.query(query);
```

If you do not have any rows in **rows**, then you'll get all accounts in org, because `Name LIKE '%%'` will match every account name.